# If $A^n=0$, then $I_n-A$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

How do I solve this problem?

$A$ is $n\times n$ and $A^n=0$. Prove that  $I_n-A$ is invertible.

Comment: please use latex/mathjax markup otherwise your question will be almost illegible .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prove that $A+I$ is invertible if $A$ is nilpotent](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140348/prove-that-ai-is-invertible-if-a-is-nilpotent). When applied to the commutative subring of the $n\times n$ matrices  generated by $A$ and $I$, it is exactly this problem.

Comment: *sigh* I would't be surprised if the solution to this problem were not the most duplicated abstract-algebra solution of all time.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the matrix $B := I_n + A + A^2 + \cdots + A^{n-1}$. Show that $(I_n - A)B = I_n$ using the relation $A^n = 0$.

Answer (score 4):

$$(I-A)(I+A+A^2 + \dots + A^{n-1}) =$$$$= I+A+A^2 + \dots + A^{n-1} - A-A^2 - \dots - A^n=$$
$$= \mbox{ everything cancels out} =I-A^n = I$$

So $I-A$ is invertible.

Answer (score 4):

If $I_n-A$ is not invertible, then it is not a $1-1$ transformation $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$, so it must have a non-zero vector $v$ such that $(I_n-A)v=0$. Then $Av=v$ and $A^nv=v$ by induction. Since $A^n=0$, this means $v=0$, contradicting the above assumption.

The algebraic proofs have the advantage that they necessarily work on infinite-dimension vector spaces. If $T:V\to V$ is a linear transformation and $T^k=0$ for some $k$, then the proof above shows that $I_V-T$ is invertible. My proof does not, because a map $V\to V$ can be $1-1$ and not be invertible when $V$ is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: No need for a contradiction: from $(I_n-A)v=0$, deduce $v=0$, and $I_n-A$ is injective, hence invertible.

Comment: @lhf: You can only deduce $v=0$ if $I_n-A$ is invertible, which is just what we are trying to prove.

Comment: Either approach is fine, but you are correct, it isn't necessary to use contradiction if we know that if $Bv=0\implies v=0$ then $B$ is invertible.

Comment: @TonyK, I meant, deduce $v=0$ as before: $A^nv=v$.

Answer (score 0):

These algebraic proofs can be extended to a stronger claim:

> The spectrum of a nilpotent operator contains only the identity (c.f. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1022937/spectrum-of-a-nilpotent-operator/)).

Reproducing Geoff Robinson's fine answer to that question, which mirrors answers above, for any complex $\lambda\neq 0$, 
$$\lambda^n I = \lambda^n I - A^n = (\lambda I - A)(\lambda^{n-1}I + \lambda^{n-2}A + \lambda^{n-3}A^2 + \cdots + A^{n-1}) $$
so this constructs an inverse to the resolvent $\lambda I - A$.

In particular, $\lambda = 1$ answers this question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another argument. Since $A^n=0$, all eigenvalues of $A$ are zero. So the Jordan form $J$ of $A=SJS^{-1}$ has all zeroes in its diagonal. Then $I-J$ is upper triangular with all the diagonal elements nonzero, so invertible. Thus
$$
I-A=S(I-J)S^{-1}
$$
is invertible.

Comment: Hi can you explain me what S table is?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking?

Comment: A=SJS−1 can you explain your theory with an example?