# Iff conditions for $f(a)=g(a)$ for a nilpotent element $a$ in a Banach algebra

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, spectral-theory, banach-algebras

> Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a Banach algebra with $1$, let $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and let $a\in \mathcal{A}$ such that $a^n=0$.

> (a) Determine $\sigma(a)$.

> (b) Let $f,g \in \mathrm{Hol}(a)$. Give a necessary and sufficient condition on $f$ and $g$ such that $f(a)=g(a)$.

For (a) I have the following:

\begin{align*}
a^n=0&\implies a^{n+k}=a^na^k=0\cdot a^k=0\,\,\text{for all $k\ge1$}\\
&\implies\|a^{n+k}\|=0\,\,\text{for all $k\ge1$}
\end{align*}

Thus, the spectral radius of $a$ is given by
\begin{align*}
r(a):&=\sup\{|\alpha|:\,\alpha\in\sigma(a)\}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\|a^n\|^{1/n}\\
&=0
\end{align*}
Hence, we must have that $\sigma(a)=\{0\}$. Is this correct?

For (b) I know that $f,g\in\text{Hol(a)}$ means by definition that $f$ and $g$ are analytic in a neighborhood of $\sigma(a)$ and so, by part (a), $f$ and $g$ are analytic in a neighborhood of $0$. From here, I am thinking to use the spectral mapping theorem, this would give
\begin{align*}
&\sigma(f(a))=f(\sigma(a))=f(0)\\
&\sigma(g(a))=g(\sigma(a))=g(0).
\end{align*}
But I am not sure how I would go from here to get necessary and sufficient conditions to have that $f(a)=g(a)$. Any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any thoughts? Tried anything? Spectral mapping theorem?  What is $\operatorname{Hol}(a)$?  Its definition might be a clue. Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1022937/spectrum-of-a-nilpotent-operator (not for general Banach algebras, but similar)

Comment: You are stating two tasks, in an imperative formulation. You do not present your efforts towards the answers, instead "rather lost ..."
I would (1) estimate that this is not well-received altogether,
(2) not wonder if your post gets closed for these reasons, more or less quickly.
Up to you to improve ...

Comment: For such a question the general advice is: see the part of the textbook just before this, and try to find something applicable.

Comment: @leslietownes Thank you, I appreciate the link. I will work on it some more when I get a chance.

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you, I will review the textbook.

Comment: Good editing work @SpiderBite ! Now a considerably improved post: +1